# find a file by the suffix substring of true absolute path

Tags: linux, shell

I met this question in my interview today.

For example, the file `1.txt`, which I want, is in `/data/users/xxx/u/a/b/c/1.txt`. Right now, I only remember that the absolute path of the file I want has the suffix `a/b/c/1.txt`. There can be a lot of different `1.txt` in my system.

Which shell command should I use to find the one with this pattern.

Comment: You can use `glob.glob("/data/users/*/u/a/b/c/1.txt")` https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-wholename` option to `find` allows you to specify pathname components along with a glob to locate files in your filesystem. You should try and tailor the start directory as much as possible, but you can start with `/` if you really have no idea where the file could be located.

In that case, you could do:

```bash
find / -type f -wholename "*a/b/c/1.txt"
```

---

You can also use `locate` (mlocate) which uses `-wholename` matching by default. An equivalent search with `locate` would be:

```bash
locate "*/a/b/c/1.txt"
```

The caveat is that `updatedb` must have been run since the file was created for it to be in the `mlocate.db`. Otherwise, the file won't be found with `locate`. (also note, `locate` is not installed by default in by all Linux distros)